# Android 13 Wake up Screen programmatically

Tags: android

Here is code working on Android 9. But on Android 13 (Samsung Galaxy) it doesn't work.

```
// Unlock screen & wake up phone

if ( deviceManger.isAdminActive( compName )) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
             | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");

    wakeLock.acquire();
}
```

Do you have any hints what should be modified for Android 13.
Thank you

I have tried but it also doesn't work

`Window window = this.getWindow();`

`window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);`
`window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);`
`window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this code works with me on Android 13

```
     PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    if (!powerManager.isInteractive()){ // if screen is not already on, turn it on (get wake_lock)
        @SuppressLint("InvalidWakeLockTag") PowerManager.WakeLock wl = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE |PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK ,"id:wakeupscreen");
        wl.acquire();
    }
```

and add these permissions to manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

Comment: I tested many other alternatives, this is the only one that really worked. Thanks for sharing.